# C++ char* to string run time error

Tags: c++, string, file, char, malloc

I have this piece of code:

```
char* mtlBuffer = readFromBinary(myfile[0]);    
string mtlBufferStr = mtlBuffer;

if (mtlBufferStr != " ")
{       
    mtlFile.open(fileLocation + "/" + mtlBufferStr.substr(7));
    if (mtlFile.is_open())
    {
        mtlFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
        mtlLength = mtlFile.tellg();
        mtlFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

        while (mtlFile.tellg() < mtlLength)
        {
            mtlFile.getline(mtlBuffer, 255);
            mtlBufferStr = mtlBuffer;
        }
    }
}
```

on the line:

```
mtlBufferStr = mtlBuffer;
```

I got a run time error:

> Win32.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

This happens on the malloc file. I have chacked what mtlBuffer stored and its:

> "# MTL written from /Users/manapoly/Desktop/Yusup/Models/Land/Lamborghini/Aventador/Aventador/Avent.obj"

The weird this is if I delete this line (and compare mtlBufferStr to the value he needs to contain):

> mtlFile.getline(mtlBuffer, 255);

The code perfectly works. Why does getLine fail the program?

Sorry about my English.

Comment: The reason most probably is that what you got from `char* mtlBuffer = readFromBinary(myfile[0]);` isn't properly NUL (`'\0'`) terminated!

Comment: slightly offtopic: why not use `std::string::assign()` instead of `operator=`?

Comment: @IosifMurariu perhaps for readability reasons.

Comment: Why even have `char* mtlBuffer`? Why not just assign to the `std::string`? You should be able to `getline` with a `std::string` later as well.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ I have checked that before. mtlBuffer contains "mtllib Avent.mtl"

Comment: crashmstr I have change it and now is is working! Buy why? I still do not understand it.

Comment: What exactly does `readFromBinary()` return? Can you write to it and is it large enough to take 255 characters? That part of the code looks really wonky.

Comment: I second @Blastfurnace. It seems like a misuse to me to re-use the result pointer for something different. Better declare a new buffer of known length. I'm also missing a check for nullptr when readFromBinary() returns.

Comment: @user3706707 Read http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is the problem.

```
mtlFile.getline(mtlBuffer, 255);
mtlBufferStr = mtlBuffer;
```

You need to read into a locally allocated buffer. For example:

```
char buf[255];
mtlFile.getline(buf, 255);
mtlBufferStr = buf;
```

`mtlBuffer` is a pointer to an internal buffer somewhere, and obviously not suitable for reuse. As a general principle, any time you reuse a variable for some different purpose expect a problem of some kind, sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
mtlFile.getline(mtlBuffer, 255);
```

looks like it expects a pointer to a pre-allocated byte buffer. And the "255" might specify the size of that buffer.
But I cannot see any allocation done in your code.
So I would say "getline" tries to write into non-allocated space.